# Why does the @EntityScan annotation not work in a microservice project (error:Not a managed type: class)?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm doing a microservice project and I decided to keep the entities in a different service. I created a service called cammon and started keeping my entities there.
I created an entity named Computer in Cammon service. I created another service called Product and added cammon service as dependecy to this service. I created controller service and repository(interface) for comptuter entity in product service.

```
Computer pathname:com.example.product.entity.Computer
Computer Controller pathname:com.example.computer.controller.ComputerController
Computer Service pathname:com.example.computer.service.ComputerService
Computer Repository pathname:com.example.computer.repository.ComputerRepository
```

When I get run ı got this error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'computerController' defined in file [...\com\example\computer\controller\ComputerController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'computerService' defined in file [...\com\example\computer\service\ComputerService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'computerRepository' defined in com.example.computer.repository.ComputerRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.example.product.entity.Computer
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at
```

I came across @EntityScan when I searched but the room is not working.

```
@EntityScan("com.example.product.entity")
public class ProductServiceApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
SpringApplication.run(ProductServiceApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

What should I do in this case?

Comment: When you say "entities are in a different service" and "dded cammon service as dependency, " do you mean separate projects/modules? Please show your project(s) structure including poms (if using Maven) or `build.gradle` files (if using Gradle).

Comment: Is com.example.product.entity.Computer annotated as @Entity?

Comment: @JohnWilliams yes its have Entity